# Iterating or Pattern Matching a element that may have inner lists in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following structure:

```
case class Something( name: String, more: List[Something] )
```

Now, you can imagine, that I want to go over all possible elements in this "Tree"

How to do it? I want to perform a Side effect over this structure:

```
Something("some", List( Something("someMore", Nil), Something("momoMore", Nil), Something("nowIwantToSee", List( ...... a lot more something  ))  ))
```

And this could go into more and more nesting structures....

???

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion:

```
def recurse(something: Something): Unit = {
  println(something.name)
  something.more.foreach(recurse)
}
```

So:

```
> val something = Something("some", List( Something("someMore", Nil), Something("momoMore", Nil), Something("nowIwantToSee", Nil)))
> recurse(something)
some
someMore
momoMore
nowIwantToSee
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jean Logeart has provided a solution that works. Only problem I see is that the function is not `tail recursive`. You can test that with `@tailrec` annotation.

You can use `pattern matching` here as follow:

```
def traverse(something: Something): Unit = {
    println(something.name)
    something match {
      case Something(name, Nil) =>
      case Something(name, x :: Nil) => traverse(x)
      case Something(name, x :: xs) => traverse(Something(x.name, xs))
    }
  }
```

Comment: C'mon.  All those `println()`s can be replaced with a single `println(something.name)` at the top, before the match.

Comment: Oh my bad, I missed that. Thanks for pointing out. I made the edit.

Comment: Ah. Now just get rid of the excess whitespace, correct the indenting, and that'll be some nice clean code.